# When does masonry container width exceed that of its parent?

Tags: javascript, jquery-masonry

I'm loving masonry but I have one small glitch: sometimes the width of the masonry container is larger than that of it's parent.  Has anyone experienced this before?  Under what circumstances does it happen?  And how do you solve it?

My site uses `isFitWidth` and re-does the layout after the browser is resized.  The container has auto margins (left and right), so it's centred.

When I slowly reduce the size of my browser I get to the point where horizontal scroll bars show up (and some of the content is out of view), before masonry recalculates and drops a column.

If I check the DOM at this point I find that the width applied to the masonry container element (by masonry) is slightly larger than the size of the parent element.  The size of the discrepancies I have seen so far are 8px and 13 px.  (It seems to depend in part on the `columnWidth` and `gutter` settings).

Note that I am not using percentages for width calculations and there are no images in my content.

I tried several things including:

- different browsers
- removing unnecessary styling (e.g. padding) from the masonry container
- removing unnecessary styling (e.g. drop shadows) from the masonry items
- using relative positioning on the container's parent
- removing unnecessary styling (e.g. margins) from the container's parent

Any ideas?